# Cannot get mysqli to work

Tags: php, class, mysqli

I am building a custom CMS that uses a class to do everything and I am now using a MYSQL connect function.

Now I want to change all the mysql functions for mysqli.

But I can't get the mysqli function to work can somebody help me ?

here is the code :

```
public function connect() {
    // Set up connection details for the site   
    $con = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
    if (!$con) {
        die("ShadowCMS could not connect to the database: " . mysql_error());
    }
    // Set up the database
    $db_select = mysql_select_db($this->db, $con);
    if(!$db_select) {
        die("ShadowCMS could not select a database: " . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

How can I change this to a mysqli connection function that will work ?

I have searched everywere but i cant find anything that will help.

Comment: Where are your mysqli_* functions?

Comment: this doesn't look like `mysqli`, this is `mysql_` wich is deprecated, please use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: People.....read the question. He is trying to change from mysql to mysqli. He is showing you his existing code, which has `mysql_*` functions and asking how to change it to `mysqli_*` functions. @WouterVanMarrum: You should probably show us the code with the `mysqli_*` functions you've tried that don't work. Then we can help diagnose the *problem*, not write your code for you.

Comment: The question was written in another manner, but still, where's the mysqli_* ? Could we have the same code, but written in the way he wants it?

Comment: I got it working thanks to some people @codecanyon forum.
Now I am going to revise all code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent 10 seconds and got this result

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Should full-fill your needs. Pay note to the example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper code

```
public function connect()
{
    $dsn = "mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->db};charset=utf8";
    $opt = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    );
    $con = new PDO($dsn,$this->username, $this->password, $opt);
}
```